# how to loop through 2 arrays after fetching data using a for

Tags: javascript, for-loop, fetch-api

when trying to loop through 2 arrays of objects fetched using the fetch API the for loop part gets ignored and will only get the else if part.

I believe I am doing something wrong but I can't wrap my head around it, any help is welcome

so the idea is to get data from a JSON file, formatted as follow:

```
{
a:["a","b","c"],
b:["d","e","f"],
}
```

this is my javascript

```
const wordsData = './profanity.json';
// gets the user input
let nickname = document.getElementById("nickname");

function filter1() {
    // empty array holder for the fetched profanity words and whitelist.

    const arrayProfanity = [];
    const arrayWhiteList = [];


type here



    fetch(wordsData)
        .then((data) => {
            return data.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            arrayProfanity.push(data.badwords);
            arrayWhiteList.push(data.whitelist);
            console.log(arrayProfanity);
            console.log(arrayWhiteList);
            let userInput = nickname.value;
            let profanity1 = arrayProfanity;
            let whiteList1 = arrayWhiteList;

            for (i = 0; i < profanity1.length; i++) {
                if (profanity1[i] == userInput) {
                    console.log("working");
                    alert("Sorry not allowed,why not try a different nickname?");
                    return false;
                }
                 else if (profanity1[i] != userInput) {
                    console.log("not working");
                }
            }
            // loops through the white list
            for (j = 0; j < whiteList1.length; j++) {
                if (whiteList1[i] == userInput) {
                    console.log("working");
                    alert("that's a good nickname!");
                    return true;
                } else if (whiteList1[i] != userInput) {
                    alert("Sorry not allowed, why not try a different nickname?");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        })

};
```

When the console logs in the fetched data I can see the arrays just fine, I  push them to another array and then runs a for loop to find any matches and send an alert if any are found.

Comment: hey @mmh4all pushing elements to an array which was declared by const is possible

Comment: Did you know pushing an array into another does not merge them? For that you can do: `array1.push(...array2)`, notice the three dots. Does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the if clause and else if clause are the same.

Try to use in if clause the **arrayProfanity**.

```
if (arrayProfanity[i] == userInput) {
     console.log("working");
     alert("Sorry not allowed,why not try a different nickname?");
     return false;
}
else if (profanity1[i] == userInput) {
     console.log("not working");
}
```

So try to test this way and check if you can get the if part.